# Use windows froms with gtk

Tags: c#, .net, windows, forms, gtk

Can I use OpenFileDialog in gtk# app for windows?
When I use this sample code in my app it's freeze and crash.
I also use Threading. It's worker with OpenFileDialog code.

```
using System;
using Gtk;
using System.Threading;
namespace Test
{
public partial class basec : Gtk.Window
{
    public basec() :
            base(Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
    {
        this.Build();
    }
    protected void OnDeleteEvent(object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
    {
        Window win = new Window();
        win.Show();
        this.Destroy();
    }
    protected virtual void OnButtonAddPClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        brows workerObject = new brows();
        Thread workerThread = new Thread(workerObject.DoWork);
        workerThread.Start();
        while (!workerThread.IsAlive);
        Thread.Sleep(1);
        workerObject.RequestStop();
        workerThread.Join();
    }
    protected virtual void OnButtonMenuClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Window win = new Window();
        win.Show();
        this.Destroy();
    }
    protected virtual void Exits(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Window win = new Window();
        win.Show();
        this.Destroy();
    }
}
}
```

Worker:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace Test
{
public class brows
{
    // This method will be called when the thread is started. 
    public void DoWork()
    {
        Stream myStream = null;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    using (myStream)
                    {
                        // Insert code to read the stream here.
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
    public void RequestStop()
    {
        _shouldStop = true;
    }
    private volatile bool _shouldStop;
}
}
```

Destroying windows is because my app use multiply window and it's my first gtk project.

Comment: convert your application to MONO...

Comment: Can you show the implementation of `DoWork()`? It sounds like you have a threading issue, but I can't see your threading code. Also why are you destroying yourself with each button click? Or making a new window with each button click? [Also GTK+ 3.20 and up allows you to use the system native file dialog, if that's what you want.](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-GtkFileChooserNative.html) (Note that it uses IFileDialog, not GetOpenFileName(), but you should be using IFileDialog in programs that require Vista and up anyway, and GTK+ 3.18 and up requires Vista and up to begin with.)

Comment: Code updated and more details.

Comment: Do you get an exception or other crash report?

Comment: IDE didn't display any error or warning and app work correctly only when I click the button for OpenFileDialog ,app freeze and crash.

Comment: Yes, but after the "freeze and crash" what do you see? Does Windows spit out a Windows Error Reporting window? Do you see anything in the Console output in your IDE?

Comment: Nothing ,no crash report or console message.

Comment: Okay, try this (and this is just a guess as to what's going on): make the thread that calls into GetOpenFileName() `[STAThread]`. All threads that use Windows's native GUI stuff need to be STA, so keep that even if this doesn't work. (I have no idea if GTK+ threads need to be STA as well; I'm not familiar with how GTK# is implemented.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set thread to STA ApartmentState resolve problem. Thank you!

```
Thread workerThread = new Thread(workerObject.DoWork);
workerThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
workerThread.Start();
```